# Pygame, create grayscale from 2d numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pygame, pygame-surface

Python 3.4, pygame==1.9.2b8

I want to draw grayscale frame.
Now, code below produce blue color, but I want to make color in range (0,255), where 0 - black. 255 -white.
How is it possible?!

```
import pygame 
import numpy as np
s = 300
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((s, s))
screenarray = np.zeros((s,s))
screenarray.fill(200)
pygame.surfarray.blit_array(screen, screenarray)
pygame.display.flip()
input()
```

- in fact I have more complex `screenarray`, where each element lie during (0,65535). So I want to convert It to grayscale.

Many thanks.

Comment: pygame use colors as three numbers (red, green, blue) so white is (0,0,0) and black is (255,255,255)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyGame use 24-bit colors as three bytes (R,G,B) so white is (0,0,0) and black is (255,255,255)

```
import pygame 
import numpy as np

SIZE = 256

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SIZE, SIZE))

screenarray = np.zeros((SIZE, SIZE, 3))

for x in range(SIZE):
    screenarray[x].fill(x)

pygame.surfarray.blit_array(screen, screenarray)

pygame.display.flip()

input()

pygame.quit()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways pygame can recognize integers as colors:

1. A 3-element sequence of RGB where each element ranges between 0-255.
2. A mapped integer value.

If you want to be able to have an array where every integer between 0-255 represent a shade of grey, you can create your own grey scale array using this information. You can create your own array by defining a class.

---

The first way would be to create a numpy array were each element is a 3-element sequence.

```
class GreyArray(object):

    def __init__(self, size, value=0):
        self.array = np.zeros((size[0], size[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        self.array.fill(value)

    def fill(self, value):
        if 0 <= value <= 255:
            self.array.fill(value)

    def render(self, surface):
        pygame.surfarray.blit_array(surface, self.array)
```

---

Creating a class based on the mapped integer value can be a bit abstract. I don't know how the values are mapped, but with a quick test it was easy to determined that every shade of grey was separated with a value of `16843008`, starting with black at `0`.

```
class GreyArray(object):

    def __init__(self, size, value=0):
        self.array = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.uint32)
        self.array.fill(value)

    def fill(self, value):
        if 0 <= value <= 255:
            self.array.fill(value * 16843008)  # 16843008 is the step between every shade of gray.

    def render(self, surface):
        pygame.surfarray.blit_array(surface, self.array)
```

---

Short demonstration. Press 1-6 to change the shade of grey.

```
import pygame
import numpy as np
pygame.init()

s = 300
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((s, s))

# Put one of the class definitions here!

screen_array = GreyArray(size=(s, s))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                screen_array.fill(0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_2:
                screen_array.fill(51)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_3:
                screen_array.fill(102)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_4:
                screen_array.fill(153)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_5:
                screen_array.fill(204)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_6:
                screen_array.fill(255)

    screen_array.render(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Very good review, thanks! Unfortunately, with recent pygame 16843008-based approach renders into something yellowish. I really wonder why.

Answer (score 0):

As of python 3.6, I've ended up with the following:

```
display = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
frame = np.array(framebuf.getData(), copy=False, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((height, width, 1))
screenarray = np.repeat(frame, 3, axis = 2).swapaxes(0, 1)
pygame.surfarray.blit_array(display, screenarray)
pygame.display.flip()
```

In this snippet, frame is a numpy array, initialized with a list coming from `framebuf.getData()`. So, it could be any grayscale bitmap, not only constant or gradient as in other examples here. We reshape array to the target display dimensions. Now we deploy `numpy.repeat` to duplicate each grayscale byte into two other channels. Lastly, we have to do `swapaxes` as the easiest way to invert width and height. Orthogonally to numpy, pygame expects screenarray with width dimension coming first, which makes it look a bit column-wise (huh, what)?

Overall, this gives ~80fps with 640x480, which is quite awful, but still much better than any explicit Python code. I guess the best would be to prepare RGB frame on the native code side...

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a grayscale image, the shape of the array must be changed using [`numpy.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) and the gray channel must be expanded to a red-green and blue color channel using [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```py
cv2Image = np.repeat(cv2Image.reshape(size[1], size[0], 1), 3, axis = 2)
```

The `pygame.Surface` object can be generated by [`pygame.image.frombuffer`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.frombuffer):

```py
surface = pygame.image.frombuffer(cv2Image.flatten(), size, 'RGB')
```

The following function converts a [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) with shape (*y*, *x*) to a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object:

```py
import numpy as np
```

```py
def numpyGrayscaleToSurface(numpyArray):
    size = numpyArray.shape[1::-1]
    numpyArray= np.repeat(numpyArray.reshape(size[1], size[0], 1), 3, axis = 2)
    surface = pygame.image.frombuffer(numpyArray.flatten(), size, 'RGB')
    return surface.convert()
```

See also [How do I convert an OpenCV (cv2) image (BGR and BGRA) to a pygame.Surface object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64183409/how-do-i-convert-an-opencv-cv2-image-bgr-and-bgra-to-a-pygame-surface-object/64183410#64183410).