# How do I convert an OpenCV image (BGR and BGRA) to a pygame.Surface object?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pygame, pygame-surface

I created images from [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/)/[*opencv-python*](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) ([`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)) and I want to convert them to a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object:

```py
def cvImageToSurface(cv2Image):

    pygameSurface = # ? create from "cvImage"

    return pygameSurface 

surface = cvImageToSurface(cv2Image)
```

Some of the images have three channels (*BGR*) and some of the images also have an [alpha channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Description) (*BGRA*). What do I have to do in `cvImageToSurface` to convert images with one of the formats into a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `shape` attribute of a [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) is the number of elements in each dimension. The first element is the height, the second the width and the third the number of channels.
A [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) can be generated by [`pygame.image.frombuffer`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.frombuffer). The 1st argument can be a `numpy.array` and the second argument is the format (`RGB` or `RGBA`).

Get the size (*width*, *height*) for the `pygame.Surface` object by slicing:

```py
size = cvImage.shape[1::-1]
```

Determine the target format for the `pygame.Surface` object, depending on the third channel:

```py
format = 'RGBA' if cvImage.shape[2] == 4 else 'RGB'
```

Since the source format is *BGR* or *BGRA*, but the target format is *RGB* or *RGBA*, the red and blue channels have to be swapped:

```py
cvImage[:, :, [0, 2]] = cvImage[:, :, [2, 0]]
```

In the case of a grayscale image, the shape of the array must be changed using [`numpy.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) and the gray channel must be expanded to a red-green and blue color channel using [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```py
cvImage = np.repeat(cvImage.reshape(size[1], size[0], 1), 3, axis = 2)
```

With his data the `pygame.Surface` object can be generated by `pygame.image.frombuffer`:

```py
surface = pygame.image.frombuffer(cvImage.flatten(), size, format)
```

To ensure that the image has the same pixel format as the display *Surface* and for optimal performance, the *Surface* should be converted with either [`convert`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) or [`convert_alpha`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha):

```py
surface = surface.convert_alpha() if format == 'RGBA' else surface.convert()
```

Complete function `cvImageToSurface`:

```py
def c2ImageToSurface(cvImage):
    if cvImage.dtype.name == 'uint16':
        cvImage = (cvImage / 256).astype('uint8')
    size = cvImage.shape[1::-1]
    if len(cvImage.shape) == 2:
        cvImage = np.repeat(cvImage.reshape(size[1], size[0], 1), 3, axis = 2)
        format = 'RGB'
    else:
        format = 'RGBA' if cvImage.shape[2] == 4 else 'RGB'
        cvImage[:, :, [0, 2]] = cvImage[:, :, [2, 0]]
    surface = pygame.image.frombuffer(cvImage.flatten(), size, format)
    return surface.convert_alpha() if format == 'RGBA' else surface.convert()
```

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import os
import pygame
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

def cvImageToSurface(cvImage):
    if cvImage.dtype.name == 'uint16':
        cvImage = (cvImage / 256).astype('uint8')
    size = cvImage.shape[1::-1]
    if len(cvImage.shape) == 2:
        cvImage = np.repeat(cvImage.reshape(size[1], size[0], 1), 3, axis = 2)
        format = 'RGB'
    else:
        format = 'RGBA' if cvImage.shape[2] == 4 else 'RGB'
        cvImage[:, :, [0, 2]] = cvImage[:, :, [2, 0]]
    surface = pygame.image.frombuffer(cvImage.flatten(), size, format)
    return surface.convert_alpha() if format == 'RGBA' else surface.convert()

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

cvImage1 = cv.imread('woodtiles.jpg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
cvImage2 = cv.imread('woodtiles.jpg', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cvImage3 = cv.imread('Apple1-256.png', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
pygameSurface1 = cvImageToSurface(cvImage1)
pygameSurface2 = cvImageToSurface(cvImage2)
pygameSurface3 = cvImageToSurface(cvImage3)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill(0)
    window.blit(pygameSurface1, pygameSurface1.get_rect(topleft = window.get_rect().inflate(-10, -10).topleft))
    window.blit(pygameSurface2, pygameSurface2.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center))
    window.blit(pygameSurface3, pygameSurface3.get_rect(bottomright = window.get_rect().inflate(-10, -10).bottomright))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```