# Neon effect in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, effects

I am working with pygame project and I need to my game cubes will have neon effect. Does pygame have a function to make neon effect or somethink like this:

```
pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 255[neon]), ...)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "neon effect"? Do you mean some kind of glow or bloom? If so, the answer is no. Pygame has no "glow" feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pygame has no "glow", "bllom" or "neon" feature. You have to use [cv2](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) and/or [numpy](https://numpy.org/) to create such an effect.

Write a function that applies an effect on a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html):

- Use [`pygame.surfarray.array3d`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.array3d) to transforms a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) to a 3D array.
- Use *cv2* to apply an effect on the image (e.g. `cv2.blur`).
- Use [`pygame.image.frombuffer`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.frombuffer) to convert the 3D array to back to a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html)
  (See [How do I convert an OpenCV (cv2) image (BGR and BGRA) to a pygame.Surface object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64183409/how-do-i-convert-an-opencv-cv2-image-bgr-and-bgra-to-a-pygame-surface-object/64183410#64183410):

```py
def create_neon(surf):
    surf_alpha = surf.convert_alpha()
    rgb = pygame.surfarray.array3d(surf_alpha)
    alpha = pygame.surfarray.array_alpha(surf_alpha).reshape((*rgb.shape[:2], 1))
    image = numpy.concatenate((rgb, alpha), 2)
    cv2.GaussianBlur(image, ksize=(9, 9), sigmaX=10, sigmaY=10, dst=image)
    cv2.blur(image, ksize=(5, 5), dst=image)
    bloom_surf = pygame.image.frombuffer(image.flatten(), image.shape[1::-1], 'RGBA')
    return bloom_surf
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import numpy
import cv2

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def create_neon(surf):
    surf_alpha = surf.convert_alpha()
    rgb = pygame.surfarray.array3d(surf_alpha)
    alpha = pygame.surfarray.array_alpha(surf_alpha).reshape((*rgb.shape[:2], 1))
    image = numpy.concatenate((rgb, alpha), 2)
    cv2.GaussianBlur(image, ksize=(9, 9), sigmaX=10, sigmaY=10, dst=image)
    cv2.blur(image, ksize=(5, 5), dst=image)
    bloom_surf = pygame.image.frombuffer(image.flatten(), image.shape[1::-1], 'RGBA')
    return bloom_surf

image = pygame.Surface((100, 100), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.rect(image, (255, 128, 128), (10, 10, 80, 80))
neon_image = create_neon(image)

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False          

    window.fill((127, 127, 127))
    window.blit(neon_image, neon_image.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center), special_flags = pygame.BLEND_PREMULTIPLIED)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: Very thanks, that will help me a lot(just said it now becouse before i dont knew how to add comment)